# File types in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, files, filemanager

I (still) have Ubuntu 12.04 on desktop. In file managers I can see file types which are specific for each file extension. E.g., *.php, *.js, *.sh are shown as "PHP script", "JS script", "Shell script". *.ods and *.xls are "ODS spreadsheet" and "XLS spreadsheet". *.c and *.h are "C source" and "C header", etc. This is FINE!

I installed xubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and there is a total mess with file types. *.php, *.js, *.sh are all "application", .txt .c .h .cpp are all "text", etc.

How do I reproduce Ubuntu 12.04's behavior?

Comment: Can you clarify the error? Perhaps post an image of folder? This could be a problem of permissions.

Comment: I believe  or this is not an error, but just a difference of configs or something like this. I will be able to post screenshots later.

Answer (score 1):

In the filemanager under "settings" in the "List Columns" tab you can configure what columns the filemanager displayes

It defaults to "Type" which is the "mess" you describe where it lumps different filetypes into categories.

Choose "MIME-type" instead. It it not exactly what you ask for, but apparently as close as it gets in 16.04

Comment: Thanks! This is better. Looks a bit ugly, but at least I am able to sort files by exact type and not mess different extensions together.

But there should be way to do this like described in the question, because I see the same behavior in all file managers. So this is configured somewhere in the system.